# UIBarButtonItem not changing colors on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, wkwebview

So in relation to my other question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814043/question-mark-when-tapping-or-holding-font-icons), 
I now have a new issue I've discovered. While on iOS 11 I can change the color on the disable buttons, but on the iOS 10.3.1 simulator, it won't change.

I'm trying to achieve the button format of Safari, where if a page can't go forward or back, it disables the buttons. The code below works on IOS 11 but not below.

```
   //Toolbar actions
BOOL ableToGoBack = [self.webView canGoBack];
BOOL ableToGoForward = [self.webView canGoForward];

if (ableToGoBack == NO) {
    back.enabled = NO;
    back.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5f];
    [self.view hideToastActivity];

}else {
    back.enabled = (self.webView.canGoBack);
}

if (ableToGoForward == NO) {
    forward.enabled = NO;
    forward.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5f];
    [self.view hideToastActivity];

}else {
    forward.enabled = (self.webView.canGoForward);
}
```

I do have a custom tool bar, But I have tried disabling the tint appearance as other people have suggested, but no luck there. As well as some other suggestions found in similar encounters.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out. Below is what is working for me. I do have a switch that controls the tint of my toolbar, so you will notice there's some extra code involved.

```
    //Toolbar actions
BOOL ableToGoBack = [self.webView canGoBack];
BOOL ableToGoForward = [self.webView canGoForward];

if (ableToGoBack == NO) {
    back.enabled = NO;
    [self.view hideToastActivity];

    BOOL isblack = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"darkKeyboard"];
    if (isblack) {
        back.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f];
        [back setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:
                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello"
                                                           size:23],
                                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f]}
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        back.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f];
        [back setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:
                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello"
                                                           size:23],
                                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f]}
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }


}else {
    back.enabled = (self.webView.canGoBack);
}

if (ableToGoForward == NO) {
    forward.enabled = NO;
    [self.view hideToastActivity];

    BOOL isblack = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"darkKeyboard"];
    if (isblack) {
        forward.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f];
        [forward setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:
                                              [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello"
                                                              size:23],
                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f]}
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        forward.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f];
        [forward setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:
                                              [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello"
                                                              size:23],
                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.1f]}
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}else {
    forward.enabled = (self.webView.canGoForward);
}
```